# Level sytem, username not retrieve

Tags: mongodb, discord.py

```
   @commands.command()
    async def lboard(self, ctx):
        if (ctx.channel.id == bot_channel):
            rankings = leveling.find().sort("xp",-1)
            i = 1
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Rankings")
            for x in rankings:
                temp = ctx.guild.get_member(x['id'])
                tempxp = x["xp"]
                embed.add_field(name=f'{i}: {temp}', value=f'Total XP: {tempxp}', inline=False)
                i += 1
                if i == 5:
                    break
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Can't get the user, it retrieves as None. If I add {temp.name} AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Using Mongodb

Comment: Did you enable `intents.members`?

Comment: yeah, that solved the problem. Thank you @ŁukaszKwieciński